how can I code in odoo with full control?
I'm currently working on a website using Odoo. It has a drag-and-drop system for building the UI, but the design and customization options are quite limited for my needs.
I would like to know if there is a way to directly code the UI using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript rather than relying on the drag-and-drop system. I found a module that allows me to insert code, but I want to have full control over the entire page's design and layout.
Do you have any advice or resources on how to achieve this or customize Odoo's UI more extensively?

If you want to learn Odoo, get the "Odoo Community" and learn how it works.
ODOO is based on Python, and follows a server template page creation, which you can fill with dynamic info, or just create your personalized HTML5 pages, with JavaScript or any other frontend library of your choice.
ODOO gives you full control over "Back Office" and "Front Office", and has a well defined modular system for different features.
The Odoo structure is not quite as simple as other modern Web development frameworks, but on the other hand, it already has many well crafted modules for multiple needs, that you can add to your package, with one click.
After learning the Community version, and if you actually need a bit more features, you might find the Enterprise version, has a lot more to offer, especially for companies, tat require accounting services, Reporting, etc.
